# Not seeing all traffic incoming from a website in the inspector under the network tab?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, web-inspector

So when I go to a website like, say https://coinmarketcap.com (that displays the prices of cryptocurrencies), in my Chrome Browser, it looks like I dont see all activity going on in the inspector under the Network tab.

Here is a screenshot to visualize the website:
[image]

I see the prices are updated live on the website (without refreshing), but I don't see any activity in the Network inspector.

There is of course activity when I load the page for the first time, but nothing after that even tho the website dynamically updates the prices? My firsts thought was, that it could be fake updates via a JS script on the client-side, but there are many websites I know where you can't see this, so what's going on here? What types of protocols are used to achieve this, because I know that WebSockets and polling (xhr) always shows up.

A screenshot of the network inspector, just be clear what I mean by that (showing traffic for the first 50 ms (loading time) and then nothing afterwards)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It using Web socket, you filter the request by `WS` and should see the `latest` ws connection.
Click on it and sees the message for this socket.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it was necessary to use a proxy like **burpsuite** in order to capture the sockets sent and received by the **client / server** here is the result it's about 72 request received in a single second

[image: Burpsuite Websocket history]

Answer (score 0):

The website you suggested is using Websockets for communication.

To see WebSockets request in WS tab in Network inspector, **You will have to open the console first then refresh the page.**

The console needs to capture the initial handshakes when communication initializes. So if you open the website first then check the console, you may not find anything in WS.